# How to automatically update the Assigned To on a User Story when state changes in Azure DevOps Board

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We have a typical board with the following columns.

1. New
2. Groomed
3. In Dev
4. Ready for QA
5. In QA
6. Ready for release
7. Released

When we click and drag a user story from one column to another, we'd like it to update the "assigned to" field automatically depending on which stage its in. We're not seeing any settings from which to accomplish this from the Azure DevOps UI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could customize the **Process** to achieve what you want:

1. Customize States for each column in user story work item type (The process for your team project should be an inherited process). Go to the **Organization Setting** -- **Process**, choose the inherited Process your team project used, and then choose user story work item type. Click **States** tab and add appropriate states for each column. Check the following example:

   [image]
2. Add rules for user story work item type. Click **Rules** tab, and add following rule for each State:

   [image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?

Comment: What about if we want to assign to a dynamic user or to a role?

Comment: We set the assigned to field like this: Then "Copy the value from...." "Activated By" to "Assigned To".